# How to return a list of objects from a cfscript function

Tags: coldfusion

I am getting used to ColdFusion. It appears cfscript makes a developer's life easier.

In my cfscript function, I need to:

1. Run a query "SELECT A, B from MyTable"
2. For each row of this query, create a new component on the fly that has three properties A, B, and C. Here, C is computed within the function.
3. Return an array of the new components.

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
<cfquery name="myq" datasource="mydsn">
    SELECT A, B
   FROM MyTable
</cfquery>

<cfscript>
function MyFunc() {
   // Do the magic and return the array
} 
</cfscript>
```

I am guessing I would use this function as I would use a query:

```
<cfset myarray=MyFunc() />
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(myarray)#">
   #myarray.A# <br />
   #myarray.B# <br />
   #myarray.C# <br />
</cfloop>
```

I would appreciate it if you can suggest me how I can accomplish this. I have been searching through Adobe documentation but haven't found a good example that I can relate to. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You're aware of the syntax error in your cfloop, right?

Comment: I am not altogether certain that CFSCRIPT makes one's life easier in this circumstance. You might just as well use the CFFUNCTION tag to write your function.

Comment: Unless outputting data, `cfscript` will ALWAYS make one's lief easier.

Comment: Lists are also different from arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm not suppose to just paste the link, but it's really all you need.

- [Query in cfscript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ffb.html)
- [Loop Query in cfscript (CF10)](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2367-ColdFusion-10-Looping-Over-Queries-Using-A-For-In-Loop-In-CFScript.htm)
- [Loop Query in cfscript (CF9)](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/166-Ask-Ben-Query-Loop-Inside-CFScript-Tags.htm)

Then just use `new xxx()` for new object, `ArrayAppend()` for constructing an array and `return` it.

Good luck, let us know if you run into any other problems.

Comment: Henry. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like

```
 <cfoutput>
 <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(myarray)#">
  #myarray.A[i]# <br />
  #myarray.B[i]# <br />
  #myarray.C[i]# <br />
 </cfloop>
 </cfoutput>
```

Overall you should consider returning a query rather than an array

```
<cfscript>
  query function MyFunc() {
  // Do the magic and return the array
  } 
</cfscript>
```

Then process it by

```
 <cfset myQuery = MyFunc()>

 <cfoutput query="myQuery">
      #A# <br />
      #B# <br />
      #C# <br />
 </cfoutput>
```

One rule of thumb in ColdFusion is: Queries are more powerful than arrays of structs. You can process them that way, but you will miss out on some very power features such as having `<cfoutput>` iterating over a query.

Comment: James. Thank you for your help. In my case, I have to do some complex calculations that could not have been possible under SQL query. Regards.